# Find a bijective function between all stricly increasing sequences and all increasing sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory

$$A = \{f \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}: \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \quad f_n \leq f_{n+1}\}$$$$B = \{f \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}: \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \quad f_n < f_{n+1}\}$$Find a bijective function $\Psi:A \rightarrow B$ or $\Psi:B \rightarrow A$.

It's easy to spot that $B \subseteq A$ and because of that it's easy to spot that there is an inective function $g: B \rightarrow A$ so $|B| \leq |A|$. But because of the $\subseteq$ I struggle to find the bijective function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider
$$(f_n)\in A\mapsto (f_n+n-1)\in B.
$$

Comment: I don't understand. Consider the identity function $id \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$: then, $id \in A$ but $(id_n + n - 1)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \notin B$ because $(id_0 + 0 - 1) = -1 \notin \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I think $0$ is not a natural number.